# How to make new varint-encoded protobuf message?

Tags: java, encoding, buffer, protocol-buffers

I have an ArrayList of protobuf messages that I'm generating and I want to know how I can generate a varint-encoded message with them.

Let's say the message I want is called "Foobar". It would be created using `protoc --java_out` I want to do this:

```
VarintFoobarVarintFoobarVarintFoobar
```

Varint should represent the length of the Foobar after it.

Once the messages are encoded into a byte array, the following code should be able to undo everything (assuming output is the ArrayList I started with and input is the encoded protobuf):

```
List<Foobar> output = new ArrayList<Foobar>();
CodedInputStream cis = CodedInputStream.newInstance(input);
for (int i = 0; !cis.isAtEnd(); i++) {
    int x = cis.readRawVarint32();
    output.add(Foobar.parseFrom(cis.readRawBytes(x)));
}
```

Comment: what sort of varint do you mean ???. In java version of protocol buffers the writeDelimitedTo method writes a varint32 then the message

Comment: Sorry. I figured it out about a week ago. It _was_ writeDelimitedTo. If you want, you can answer the question to get full credit for knowing the answer. After all, you should deserve it.